# How do I get a randomly generated ip back from ping

Tags: batch-file, ping

What I want to do is generate a random ip, ping it, and then, if the ip comes back as a valid ip, I want it to send the ip to a new notepad. This is what I have so far...

```
:Start
@set /a a=(%random% * 99 / 32768 + 1)
@set /a b=(%random% * 999 / 32768 + 1)
@set /a c=(%random% * 999 / 32768 + 1)
@set /a d=(%random% * 9 / 32768 + 1)
@set e=%a%.%b%.%c%.%d%
PING %e%
GOTO Start
```

I would like to make it take the ip it just pinged, and if it comes back valid, to put it in a notepad. Thanks! Also I want this to be able to repeat. 
Please leave a comment if you know how I can do this correctly!

Comment: most reliable way is to search for `TTL` in `ping`s output. So `ping %a%.%b%.%c%.%d% |find "TTL" && echo %a%.%b%.%c%.%d% is up>>running.txt` should work. `&&` works as "if previous command was successful then..."

Comment: @Stephan, it is better to search for `TTL=`, else you can get an `TTL` expired error and consider it as a valid response.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, nmap's ping scan feature could also be a solution.

Comment: @Stephan, [TTL expired in transit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958615.aspx) or [TTL expired during reassembly](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958616.aspx). Old sources but still valid

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /l %%a in (0) do (
        set /a  "A=!random! %% 255", ^
                "B=!random! %% 255", ^
                "C=!random! %% 255", ^
                "D=!random! %% 255"

        ping -w 1000 -n 1 "!A!.!B!.!C!.!D!" | find "TTL=" > nul && (
            >>"online.txt" echo !A!.!B!.!C!.!D!
        )
    )
```